# Passing appended values through json object to be sent to jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I have this appended codes here in my javascript that adds a new row every time the button is clicked to add a new employee.

Here is the code, which is working fine.

```
tab_workers.on('click', '.add-workers', function (e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var iRow = $('tbody tr:last',tab_workers).index() + 1;
        var nRow = $("<tr>\n" +
                "<td width='30%'><input name='worker_name_"+ iRow +"' class='form-control' placeholder='Name' /></td>\n" +
                "<td width='50%'><input name='worker_address_"+ iRow +"' type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Address'></td>\n" +
                "<td width='14%'><input name='worker_phone_"+ iRow +"' type='text' maxlength='11' onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' class='form-control' placeholder='Phone No.'></td>\n" +
                "<td width='3%'><a class='btn btn-outline btn-circle btn-sm red del-workers pull-right'><i class='fa fa-remove'></i>Remove</a></td>" +
                "</tr>\n");

        $('tbody',tab_workers).append(nRow);
```

Then I have this code to sent it into the ajax post method, by wrapping it into javascript object first.

```
var workers = [];
    $("[name^=worker_name]",tab_workers).each(function(i, wname){
        //var workername = $("[name=worker_name_"+i+"]");
        var workeradd = $("[name=worker_address_"+i+"]");
        var workerphone = $("[name=worker_phone_"+i+"]");

        workers.push({
            uwiName: $(wname).val(),
            uwiAddress: $(workeradd).val(),
            uwiPhone: $(workerphone).val()
        });
    });

    var workerdetails = {
            umkeiWorkerInfo: workers,
        };

    console.log(workerdetails);
```

The console.log above, returns null for all the fields(name, address, phones).

Here is the ajax part,

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: 'home/umkei/ssuForm/create/workers',
    data: JSON.stringify(workerdetails),
    contentType : "application/json",
    success: function(d){
    Metronic.unblockUI(el);
    showMetronicAlert('success','check',msgSuccess);
    console.log(d);
    }
});
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is `tab_workers` parent `table` element ? Is `.each()` called before user enters text  at `input` elements ?

Comment: Create a demo using actual html that replicates problem

Answer (score 0):

I solved this, I use FOR loop instead of .EACH()

```
var workers=[];
var w = $("[name^=worker_name]",tab_workers);
var i;

for(i=1; i<=w.length;i++){
    var workername = $("[name^=worker_name_"+i+"]");
    var workeradd = $("[name^=worker_address_"+i+"]");
    var workerphone = $("[name^=worker_phone_"+i+"]");

workers.push({
    uwiName: workername.val();
    uwiAddress: workeradd.val();
    uwiPhone: workerphone.val();
    //some other values
    });
}
```